# I Want To Make Change Color Button With Click Them With Bloc (BlocProvider)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bloc

I don't mean how to make a theme I know this

but I mean how do make change the `color button` when clicking change to purple or purpleAccent

[image]

I try BlocProvider, I save this in a function

```
 static BmiCubit get(BuildContext context) => BlocProvider.of(context);
```

and in the `widget color` add inline if

```
    isMale == true ? Colors.purpleAccent : Colors.purper;
```

but isn't working

Comment: Can you include full sample snippet with cubit that will reproduce the error

Comment: it's don't give an error in the console it shows in the UI of app (don't change the color button)